# How to link all requests to index.php and link sitemap.xml to sitemap.php in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, sitemap

This is a piece of code, which I have collected from different post on stackoverflow:

```
DirectoryIndex /index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subDir

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*),!^(sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt) /index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

Linking all requests to index.php works well but sitemap.xml to sitemap.php doesn't work at all. Just see a error message when open sitemap.xml. The sitemap.php file exists and works well, sitemap.xml doesn't exist and need to be substituted with sitemap.php when requesting

Answer (score 0):

1) All links Requests to `index.php` try following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

2) First of all, re-add the [L] flag. Second, if one rule supersedes the other, check your rewrite rules regex to make them better matching, like the whole request:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ xmlsitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap$ sitemap.php [L]
```

The L flag will prevent to run additional rules if one already matched (but still can trigger an internal redirect, see as well the END flag instead of the L flag).